# False Error: A constructor name should not start with a lowercase letter babel/new-cap

Tags: babeljs, yeoman-generator

Well I have an false positive error with Babel.

This is the error in the console.

```
ERROR in ./src/app/playlist/playlist.js

/Users/macbook-lucas/refreex/src/app/playlist/playlist.js
  6:23  error  A constructor name should not start with a lowercase letter  babel/new-cap

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

 @ ./src/app/playlist/index.js 12:16-37
 @ ./src/index.js
```

And here is the code:

```
import {webtorrent} from 'webtorrent';

class PlaylistController {
  contructor() {
    this.TorrentId = 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:6a9759bffd5c0af65319979fb7832189f4f3c35d&dn=sintel.mp4&tr=wss%3A%2F%2Ftracker.btorrent.xyz&tr=wss%3A%2F%2Ftracker.fastcast.nz&tr=wss%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openwebtorrent.com&ws=https%3A%2F%2Fwebtorrent.io%2Ftorrents%2Fsintel-1024-surround.mp4';
    this.Client = new webtorrent();
  }
}

export const playlist = {
  templateUrl: "app/playlist/playlist.html",
  controller: PlaylistController,
  bindings: {
    playlist: '<'
  }
};
```

Comment: I don't know anything about Babel, but my instinct says that the expression `new foo()` is supposed to construct an object of class `foo`. So if class names must start with capital letters, that would have to be `new Foo()`. Or `new Webtorrent()`, in your case (see line 6, as per the error message).

Comment: Not sure what about this you feel is a false-positive. Somewhere in your linter config, you've enabled `new-cap`, and now you're using a constructor that is lowercase. The rule is failing as it should.

Comment: I think you are getting confused, this error is from ESLint, not Babel. Babel will compile this code with no problem, but you've enabled an ESLint rule  that causes an error for lower-case constructors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like rici says:

I don't know anything about Babel, but my instinct says that the expression new foo() is supposed to construct an object of class foo. So if class names must start with capital letters, that would have to be new Foo(). Or new Webtorrent(), in your case (see line 6, as per the error message). –